# How to put an element to a map and return the map

Tags: kotlin

Consider this function, where we try to add an element to result of `toMap(): MutableMap<String, Any>`:

```
fun add(key: String, value: Any): MutableMap<String, Any> {
    val map = asMap()
    map.put(key, value)
    return map
}
```

This is fairly simple, but I wonder if it could be possible to be simplified to a "one-liner"? Something like:

```
fun add(key: String, value: Any): MutableMap<String, Any>
    = asMap().magicPut(key, value)
```

EDIT: Obviously I was not clear enough: `asMap()` is a user defined function that returns a MutableMap with some entries. The `add` method should add to this already existing map.

EDIT2: Based on comments I renamed `toMap()` to `asMap()`.

Comment: Why not use `val map = mutableMapOf(key to value)`, and remove that add() function completely? https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/mutable-map-of.html

Comment: The `toMap()` naming is causing confusion in the answers, because `toMap()` exists in Kotlin stdlib and has a completely different meaning.  `asMap()` or `defaultMap()` or another name would help clarify this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can simplify your function to

```
fun add(key: String, value: Any) = toMap().apply { put(key, value) }
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use this helper function:

```
mutableMapOf(key to value)
```

It is part of Kotlin standard lib [(link)](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/mutable-map-of.html).

Update for explanation from comment:

Create extension function on `MutableMap<String, Any>`

```
fun MutableMap<String, Any>.add(key: String, value:Any) = apply { put(key to value) }
```

Then call this on your existing map `map.add("key", "value")`. This way you can chain your add calls.

Comment: I am aware of this, but how can it help me inline the whole method?

Comment: @Vojtěch your add() function does the same thing as mutableOf(), and has a less clear name. Just remove your add() function, and use mutableMapOf directly.

Comment: Maybe I was not clear enough, toMap would return already existing map with some entries.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to do that yourself. You could simply: `asMap().plus(key to value)`.

Documentation [here](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/plus.html).

Answer (score 0):

This is your code.

```
fun add(key: String, value: Any): MutableMap<String, Any> {
    val map = toMap()
    map.put(key, value)
    return map
}
```

The body of the function `add()` can be converted to a single expression.
So, the modified code will be:

```
fun add(key: String, value: Any): MutableMap<String, Any> {
    return toMap().apply { put(key, value) }
}
```

When a function returns a single expression, the curly braces can be omitted and the body is specified after a `=` symbol. So, the modified code will be:

```
fun add(key: String, value: Any) = toMap().apply { put(key, value) }
```